# The method getCellTypeEnum() is undefined for the type XSSFCell

Tags: java, excel-reader

Can someone help me to update the below code since `getCellTypeEnum()` shows error:

> The method getCellTypeEnum() is undefined for the type XSSFCell

Any help will be appreciated.

```java
private void prepareInnerList(List<String> innerList, XSSFRow xssfRow, int j) {
    switch (xssfRow.getCell(j).getCellTypeEnum()) // Error is thrown at this line
    {

    case BLANK:
        innerList.add("");
        break;

    case STRING:
        innerList.add(xssfRow.getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
        break;

    case NUMERIC:
        innerList.add(xssfRow.getCell(j).getNumericCellValue() + "");
        break;

        case BOOLEAN:
        innerList.add(xssfRow.getCell(j).getBooleanCellValue() + "");
        break;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html), `getCellTypeEnum()` is deprecated.

Use `getCellType()` instead.